# mint KDE 18.2 is write protected.

Tags: linux, google-chrome, linux-mint, kde

when I open some application (google chrome, libre office writter) in my **linux mint KDE 18.2**, my hard disk becomes write protected,I could not create,modify or download  a file. It shows message like

*"/home/akasnil/.config/trash.sorc" not writable.Please contact your system administrator.*

how to solve this?? 
P.s.  I've tried the similar solution given [here](https://superuser.com/questions/400185/fix-kde-permissions-after-sudo-startx?newreg=d2638b3f744e44dc9c016dfb2b2b0107) but it did not work & I'm a newbie in this platform.

Comment: What does `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` say? If your entire partition had some sort of error it could switch to being read-only, check `mount` and see if it's `rw` or `ro` . And check the permissions of the file, `ls -la` should do it.

Comment: Same thoughts. If there is an error, HDD file systems are typically remounted R/O to prevent further damage. So, you could have some kind of error occurring when you read these files. Install [smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) to get an idea of the health status of your HDD.